# How to use administration session, to let user to access another page created in same server in joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I've created a PHP file, and put in my server, within joomla, but for a while, this page don't have any protection.

I want to use "administration login" to let the user to access my new page with these credentials.

If user not logged in administration, my page don't let user to access and redirect to another page.

I think that I need to use Sessions, but I don't know how to.

Can anyone help me?

Sorry for my english, and thanks a lot

Comment: Could you provide sample urls or similar ones to help understand. is this just a /newfile.php in the same directory as Joomla or a module or something written in joomla framework?

Comment: Is just a www.site.com/file.php, and I want that if I login www.site.com/administrator file.php get login session

Answer (score 1):

just check logged in user's type with basic joomla user object.

```
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

$user = JFactory::getUser();
if($user->usertype == "deprecated"){ 
/*deprecated means super admin also you can check and allow user group level from
[groups] => Array
        (
            [8] => 8
        )

admin user logged in do what ever you want here
*/

}
else{

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplcation();
$mainframe->redirect('url','message ','message type'); //last param like error,warning success , info etc
}
```

hope its helps..

Comment: Thank you. But after log into administration, when I go to my page is always redirecting to 'url'.

Comment: Are you sure `$user->usertype` will work with Joomla 2.5? If I rightly remember, this was removed and was only available in Joomla 1.5

Comment: @Lodder it works on 2.5 but not in 3.x I checked also.Bcoz the user table structure changed in j3.x

Comment: Ahh fair enough then. Maybe they just deprecated it in 2.5 then

Comment: @JoaoPaulo just print_r($user) before redirect and make sure you have user object available there

Comment: @Jobin Jose. Returned this JUser Object ( [isRoot:protected] => [id] => 0 [name] => [username] => [email] => [password] => [password_clear] => [usertype] => [block] => [sendEmail] => 0 [registerDate] => [lastvisitDate] => [activation] => [params] => [groups] => Array ( ) [guest] => 1 [lastResetTime] => [resetCount] => [_params:protected] => JRegistry Object ( [data:protected] => stdClass Object ( ) ) [_authGroups:protected] => [_authLevels:protected] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) [_authActions:protected] => [_errorMsg:protected] => [_errors:protected] => Array ( ) [aid] => 0 )

Comment: that means the user is guest(value 1) you are not yet logged in. login with admin user.

Comment: I pasted this after login in mysite.com/administrator and when i went to mysite.com/mysessionpagetest.php to test your code i got this code.

Comment: am betting Joao is logging into the administrative backend not logging in frontend as an administrator...note they are completely independent logins in joomla..hence he gets the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, you could do something like this
https://github.com/Buddhima/Joomla-HttpLogin-plugin